# Can't create a schema extension

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a schema extension in Microsoft Graph API.

But it has failed with error message "Property type is invalid for target types".

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions
Content-type: application/json

{
    "id":"extendedData",
    "description": "Graph Learn training courses extensions",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Event"
    ],
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "courseId",
            "type": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "name": "materialId",
            "type": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "name": "courseType",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Property type is invalid for target types.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": ...,
            "request-id": ...,
            "client-request-id": ...
        }
    }
}
```

Why can't I create a schema extension and what error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Integer** type in `properties` is not supported for **Event** `targetTypes` based on [Supported property data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionschemaproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0#supported-property-data-types).

You could change them to **String**.

Please note that you may will encounter a new error: `Attempt to update complex extension definition on application: dexxxxx5-d9f9-48b1-a8ad-b7xxxxx25064 belonging to different context.`

If you get this error, it means you still need to put an `owner` property in the JSON payload. (If you don't get this error, it's unnecessary to put `owner` property)

Register an Azure AD app and put the application id as the `owner`.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions
Content-type: application/json

{
    "id":"extendedData",
    "description": "Graph Learn training courses extensions",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Event"
    ],
    "owner": "{application id of an Azure AD app}",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "courseId",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "materialId",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "courseType",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This worked for me and `owner` property was created automatically.

Comment: @hotcakedev Glad to know that. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you:)

Comment: What is the reason why `Event` target type doesn't support `Integer` property type?

Comment: @hotcakedev Sorry I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I was trying to use this created schema extension while creating a new event by patching the event. But it says an error `"A type named 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type."`. Why does this happen?

Comment: @hotcakedev Please share your request so that I can have a test from my side.

Comment: I tried this to add the schema extension just I created to the new event. `PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar-group-id}/events/{event-id}` and `{"courseId": "10", "materialId": "22", "courseType": "video"}`. It occurs an error `A type named 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type`.

Comment: {extendedData: {"courseId": "10", "materialId": "22", "courseType": "video"}}

Comment: could you check my another question? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65614549/cant-create-an-event-with-extended-data)