# Can't create an event with extended data

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to create a calendar event with extended data using Microsoft Graph API.(actually, I am trying to converting the existing open extension to schema extension since I couldn't filter the non-id extended value of the open extension.)

Before my try, I have already created [my schema extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603715/cant-create-a-schema-extension) successfully and creating a calendar event with the schema extension responses an error code "BadRequest" and message "Requests must contain extension changes exclusively".

I tried to do this by following the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups#3-create-a-new-group-with-extended-data).

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar-group-id}/events

{
  "subject": "schema extension test",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "schema extension test"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2021-01-22T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2021-01-23T14:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
  },
  "attendees": [],
  "extendedData": {
      "courseId": "11",
      "materialId": "22",
      "courseType": "video"
  }
}

response: 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Requests must contain extension changes exclusively.",
        "innerError": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Without `extendedData`, creating the event responses success, and after creating the event, if I `patch` the event with only `extendedData`, it responses an error "A type named 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type".

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar-group-id}/events/{event-id}
    
    {
      "extendedData": {
          "courseId": "11",
          "materialId": "22",
          "courseType": "video"
      }
    }

response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBodyRead",
        "message": "A type named 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type.",
        "innerError": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to succeed when I used Graph API explorer with signed in user by consent `Calendars.Read` permission.

But if I try the same thing in postman, it doesn't work.

I already have granted all calendar permissions including delegated and application permissions in Azure.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because your schema extension name is not `extendedData`.

When you use `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions` to create an extension for Event type, the real name will be prefixed.

Like this:

[image]

And based on this [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/graph/known-issues#creating-a-resource-instance-and-adding-schema-extension-data-at-the-same-time) of Microsoft Graph:

> You cannot specify a schema extension in the same operation as
> creating an instance of contact, event, message, or post. You must
> first create the resource instance and then do a PATCH to that
> instance to add a schema extension and custom data.

So we need to create the event first and then update it.

When updating the event, we need to specify the real extension name:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Allen Wu. Actually I named the schema extension as `contoso_extendedData`. You know it is {my actual domain name}_{schemaName}. So if I request `GET /schemaExtensions/contoso_extendedData`, then it responses the correct extension.

Comment: And it seems like I can't use `$filter` for the extension properties even I succeed to create events with extended data, right? refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/graph/known-issues#filtering-on-schema-extension-properties-not-supported-on-all-entity-types) using my Graph API.

Comment: You can PATCH the event in Graph Explorer but not in Postman? Using the fully same request?

Comment: @hotcakedev Sorry, forgot to @ you:(. Can you answer the questions above?

Comment: Yes, correct. After granting permissions in Graph explorer, there was no error to patch an event with schema extension. But after patching, I was not able to get the event with the schema extension.

Comment: @hotcakedev The same requests gets different results. The only thing I can think of is access token. Compare the decoded results of the 2 access token in https://jwt.io.

Comment: I already tried to compare 2 access tokens, they are not the same and also have the different permissions. But I think I set all correct permissions. `Calendar.ReadWrite` permission is consented, not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: @hotcakedev Try to use the access token in Graph explorer to patch event in Postman.

Comment: I am sure it would work. But I should use auto-generated access token, not manual one.

Comment: @hotcakedev Yes. I just want to know if the cause ii the access token. If the access token from Graph Explorer can work in Postman, the access token got from Postman should be incorrect. Please share how you get it in Postman. Provide a screenshot is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I think this is useless because I should filter the specific extended property's value after creating an event with extended data that's what I need. I already mentioned this. I can't use $filter for the extension properties for event types, right?

Comment: @hotcakedev Yes. We cannot use `$filter` for the extension properties for event types.